# If $\nabla_{p}f(v)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $v$ in the direction of $p,$ then what is $(\nabla_{\bullet}f)(v)?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request

Let $p\in\mathbb{R}^{n},$ and let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}.$ Then, the directional derivative of $f$ at $v$ in the direction of $p$ is
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(v+hp)-f(v)}{h},$$
whenever the limit exists and is finite. We may denote this value by $(\nabla_{p}f)(v).$

Now fixing suitable $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n},$ we may consider the values of $(\nabla_{\bullet}f)(v).$ This is a function that takes as input a vector $p$ and outputs $(\nabla_{p}f)(v),$ the directional derivative of $f$ at $v$ in the direction of $p.$

Does this last function $(\nabla_{\bullet}f)(v)$ have a name, in the same way that the directional derivative has a name? I feel as though I have seen it come up somewhere before, perhaps in something to do with differential geometry; even if it doesn't have a name, is it somehow a useful concept?

Comment: Not quite sure how to tag this. If this is indeed relevant to differential geometry, should I edit the tags later to include the (differential-geometry) tag?

Comment: The gradient of $f$.

Comment: @mathematician: Oh! As in, $(\nabla_{\bullet}f)(v) = \langle \nabla f(v),\bullet\rangle?$ I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is literally the differential of $f$. For instance, you can check that in "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Barrett O'neill he defines the differential $1$-form of $f$ by the function $df$ such that

$$df(p_v)=\nabla_p f(v)$$

where $p_v$ represents that the vector $p$ is at position $v$. So in this formulation, you fix the position $v$ as you described, and you take $p$, the direction vector, as input.

This is not quite the gradient of $f$.

Comment: I knew I had seen it discussed somewhere! Obviously, I didn't have the book on-hand. Thank you for clarifying the situation.